# Delay required between a file created via external program using system() and opening it via open()?

Tags: c, linux, file, race-condition, ext2

I'm trying to create a TAR archive from my program and then opening the archive for further processing. I have a 2 second delay between calling `system()` and `open()`. So far, it works fine, but I'm not sure why the 2 second delay is necessary or if it's the correct solution.

Without the delay, I get error code 2 (ENOENT "No such file or directory") from the `open()` call. My first thought was the filesystem wasn't updating itself fast enough and `open()` couldn't find the file. But what if the system is really busy? Do I need a longer delay? Should I loop until `open()` succeeds instead of the delay? Is the problem something completely different?

**UPDATE**
The root filesystem is EXT2. `/tmp` is mounted in RAM using TMPFS. I'm using `tar` to *create* an archive, not extract contents of one. Essentially, my program is supposed to create an archive of some log files and send them over the network (that's why I open the archive after creating it).

```
int return_value = system("/bin/tar -czf /tmp/logs.tar.gz /var/log/mylogs.log* &> /dev/null");
// error checks on return_value as described here: http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait
if(return_value != 0) {
  return return_value;
}
//usleep(2000000);
return_value = open("/tmp/logs.tar.gz", O_RDONLY | O_LARGEFILE, 0);
// success or failure depending on whether there's a delay or not
```

Comment: What happens if you use `popen`?

Comment: Exactly, this is a job for `popen()`. Tutorials teaching `system()` should be given the axe.

Comment: `popen()` has the same end result as `system()`. I.E. the `open()` call fails in the same way without a delay.

Comment: What filesystem are we talking about here, anyway? Is network transport involved? Are you perhaps the victim of a crappy consumer NAS device? (Been there, seen that... for example, a NAS dev exportings its files using CIFS - and never storing filestamps, which means rsync could not do its job properly.)

Comment: Perhaps the problem is elsewhere. You should show actual code to get real help.

Comment: @fge Does `popen()` have the same warning about suid and sgid programs as `system()`? Or is the best solution `fork()/exec()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You think you are redirecting tar's output with "&>", but actually you are running it in the background, because system() happens to invoke a shell that doesn't support &> and so interprets it as "&" followed by ">".  The delay causes your program to wait long enough that tar completes.

The fix is to modify your command to use syntax that your shell supports.  Throwing the error output from tar is probably a mistake in any case.

Answer (score 2):

You could even avoid running an external `tar` command by using [libtar](http://www.feep.net/libtar/) directly in your program.

---

**ADDED**

And you should show us your program. I'm pretty sure that if the call to `system` just extracted some file thru `tar`, it is available just after a *successful* `system` call, e.g. something like:

```
 int err = system("/bin/tar xf /tmp/foo.tar bar");
 int fd = -1;
 if (err == 0)
      fd = open("bar", O_RDONLY);
 // fd is available
```

there is no reason to wait a few seconds in this code. You are probably doing more complex things, or you forgot to test the result of `system`

Comment: Not installed on my system, `tar` is and it's much simpler to use. Also, there are other external programs executed that may benefit.

Comment: I've added an example of `system` with tar which should work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would try:

1. fork/exec tar yourself, and have your parent collect the tar-child.  If system is introducing a race condition with the file system, taking control of the child process creating/reaping may help.
2. `touch` an empty file (`fopen` for writing and `close`) and then `tar` into into the new file.
3. Give `tar` the `--verify` option; the file has to exist in order to be verified :)

Comment: yes, but if we're operating under the assumption that there is a bug somewhere, this will rule out the possibility that it's a code/library issue, letting us focus on other things.